# Why doesn't this summation work on NYSE 1-month high/low data?

Tags: pine-script

I'm experimenting with indicators and market internal data. The script below is attempting to sum the difference between NYSE 1-month high issues - NYSE 1-month low issues.

```
//@version=4
study("LFG NYHL")

var nyhlm_sum = float(0)

nyhlm = security("M1HN", timeframe.period, close) - security("M1LN", timeframe.period, close)

nyhlm_sum := nyhlm_sum[0] + nyhlm[0]    // this doesn't work!
// nyhlm_sum := nyhlm_sum[0] + close[0] // this works as expected

plot(nyhlm, title="NYHL1M", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=color.blue, transp=55)
plot(nyhlm_sum, title="NYHL1M Sum", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=color.red, transp=55)
```

As coded, I get no plot for the summed series. However, if I change it to simply sum the current symbol's closing price (commented out), then it sums as expected.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange behavior of the translator, perhaps it is worth writing about this case to the technical support of the Tradingview. I can't explain why this is happening, perhaps because these tickers are meaningful only on daily intervals.
I suggest the workaround that works.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (LFG NYHL)")

var nyhlm_sum = float(0)

nyhlm = security("M1HN", timeframe.period, close) - security("M1LN", timeframe.period, close)

//nyhlm_sum := nyhlm_sum[0] + nyhlm[0]    // this doesn't work!
// nyhlm_sum := nyhlm_sum[0] + close[0] // this works as expected
nyhlm_sum := cum(nyhlm)    // this works as expected

plot(nyhlm, title="NYHL1M", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=color.blue, transp=55)
plot(nyhlm_sum, title="NYHL1M Sum", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=color.red, transp=55)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `cum()` function, thank you for that. It does exactly what I was looking for.